# In Java, how can I foresee round-off errors if the rounding is inconsistent? e.g. 0.03 * 100 = 10.029999 but 10.05 * 100 = 10.0500001?

Tags: java

So, I'm just starting out learning and I'm aware that rounding-error questions are the most common on here. But I am unable to find one that gives a clear answer about why this particular thing happens, or rather, *how* will I know what to look for? I understand that it happens because of the way the variable are stored, and that there's a limit for how much decimal places they can hold, but I'm unsure why its different for each digit. Other than that explanation, I can't find anything further.

My textbook warns me to be careful with rounding errors, and I do know how to correct them to the decimal place that I want. But still, I want to know *how* we can brace ourselves for what numbers it is likely to happen. We can ask the console to print to check and make sure that our numbers are correct, during the programming process, but is there some way to 'detect' it before it even happens or be weary of which numbers do what?

Some numbers have no rounding error. Example: 10.02 * 100 = 1002.

But 10.03 * 100 = 1002.9999999999999

10.04 * 100 = 1003.9999999999999

10.05 * 100 = 1005.0000000000001

If it has to do with binary, why isn't 4 safe?

[Here's a snippet from my textbook:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HMtC.png)

Comment: As comment despite already being (correctly) closed: the idea that "if it has to do with binary, why isn't 4 safe" applies here deserves a response: the properties of integer numbers do not let you conclude anything about the properties of fractional numbers. Even in maths the rules for integers and fractions are very different.

Comment: Also, `.04` isn't `4`.

Comment: Then just always round to whatever precision you need, or use BigDecimal